# add css to :last-child but only if it's not :odd

Tags: jquery

I have a list of dynamically generated divs and I have this script in order to make alternating background colors - for IE's sake.

```
<style type="text/css">
.box { height:30px; width:100px; background-color:#fff; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".box:odd").css("background-color", "#f1f1f1");
    });
</script>
```

My html:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
...
```

I would like to apply a special css style to the :last-child, but only if the :last-child is not :odd - meaning only if it has a white background.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($('.box').length-1%2!=0){
        $(".box:odd").filter(":last").css({"background":"red"});            
    }
});
```

here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jYxeA/

Answer (score 4):

```
 $(".box:last").not(':odd').css("background-color", "#f1f1f1");
```

Answer (score 4):

CSS only:

```
.box:last-child:nth-child(even) { /* Special CSS here */ }
```

It's better than using jquery.